# Are caches the same across devices with the same apple A# chips?

Tags: ios, arm, cpu, cpu-architecture

I was wondering if it would be possible to determine the cache hierarchy and block size of devices running my app based on what chip they have. I am able to detect what device they are using and therefore what processor they have. Would this therefore make it possible to detect these properties of the caches on the devices based on what is published online for A9, A8, A7 etc chips?

Comment: some ARM cores have CPUID registers that have this information for the L1 cache, beyond that it is the chip vendor (or additional ARM ip that has been purchased).  You would need good knowledge/documentation for IP beyond the ARM core.

Comment: Although unlikely it is also possible that cache geometry can change between steppings of a specific chip  A7 B0 could use a different geometry than A7 A3...